# How to search for a time value in a log file using shell and awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a script where a user provides a date, start time and end time. The script will take these values and scan a log file to search for key words in the log file that fall within the time range. When a user uses AM times (Example: 0700 to 0900 - this is 7am to 9am) as a range or PM times (Example: 1400 to 1600 - this is 2pm to 4pm) as a range the script works fine. when they use an AM start time (starting with a zero - 0700) and an end time (doesn't start with zero - 1000 (this is 10am) the script does not function properly.

Here is the line in question that I'm having problems with

```
echo "Number of ${shipmentTags[$i]} shipments processed in \
    log file log$logDate/$logFileName is:
    `cat $logDirectory/log$logDate/$logFileName | 
        awk -F":" '$1$2 >= '"$startTime"' && $1$2 <= '"$endTime"' {print $0}' |
        grep ${shipmentStrings[$i]} | 
        wc -l`"
```

Thanks. I've copied here just some dummy data of what the log would look like.

```
07:00:01.124 dfsdfjsdflkjsdfkljsdflkjEDIRequestServiceModule/Routedasdfkl
07:05:02.123 fsldjfsdfskdfjsdfsdkfjEDIRequestServiceModule/Rouedsdfjsdfj
07:10:33.233 sdkjfasdflkjasdfaskdfjasdfkljEDIRequestServiceModule/Routed
09:30:02.222 sefsklfjsdfljksdfEDIRequestServiceModule/Routedasdfdf
14:00:12.222 sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfEDIRequestServiceModule/Routed sdfsdfs
14:01:22.223 sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfEDIRequestServiceModule/Routed sdfsdfsdf
17:00:22.222 sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfEDIRequestServiceModule/Routedsdfsdfsdf
18:00:33.333 sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
```

If anyone wants to see the whole script, just reply and i can cut and paste it into here as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AWK's variable passing. You won't have to do all that awkward quoting.

```
awk -F":" -v start=$startTIME -v end=$endTime '$1$2 >= start && $1$2 <= end {print $0}'
```

Don't use `cat`. You can either do:

```
awk ... filename
```

or

```
< filename awk ...
```

Also, AWK can do the grepping and counting for you:

```
< $logDirectory/log$logDate/$logFileName awk -F":" -v start=$startTIME -v end=$endTime -v selection=${shipmentStrings[$i]} '$0 ~ selection { if ($1$2 >= start && $1$2 <= end) count++} END {print count}'
```

Also, you should probably use a variable and shorten your `echo`. And use `$()` instead of backticks:

```
shipmentcount=$(... awk ...)
echo "Number of ... is: $shipmentcount"
```

Or even let the `END` clause in the AWK script print the message:

```
< $logDirectory/log$logDate/$logFileName \
awk ... -v file=$logDirectory/log$logDate/$logFileName \
    '... END {print "Number of "selection" shipments ... "file" ... is: " count}'
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, I tried your changes and i'm not getting any counts. They are coming up as zero. The problem i was initially experiencing was when the from-time starts with a leading zero such as 7am which the user would input as 0700 and the to-time is input as anytime after 0959.  This is when the script wouldn't work.  If both times were after 0959 or before 0959, the script would work.  Let me know if you would like me to try to copy the entire script here.  I feel like there is a problem with $1$2 in the script..for some reason the comparison with the time value in the log file is causing prob

Comment: @user389721: Try this: `startTime=0700; endTime=1000; echo "09:30:02.222 sefsk" | awk (the rest of my first AWK command)`. You should get the complete echoed string back out. Now try that with just the AWK part of the line that you posted. Nothing is printed. Do you get the same results from these two tests? **Also** try adding this in your script right before the line you posted and try your before 10/after 10 input and post what is output by it: `echo "start: ..${startTime}.. end: ..${endTime}.."`

Comment: Hi Dennis,  I ended up figuring it out after pulling my hair out.  Here's what i came up with and it works great.  I could probably clean it up a bit with using more awk statements but i'll take what i got.  Here's the new fixed line:

echo "Number of ${shipmentTags[$i]} shipments processed in log file log$logDate/$logFileName is:`cat $logDirectory/log$logDate/$logFileName | awk -F: -v start=$startTime -v end=$endTime '(($1$2) + 0) >= start && (($1$2) + 0) <= end {print $0}' | grep ${shipmentStrings[$i]} | wc -l`"

Thank you for all your help though..it lead me in the right direction.